# TypeError: _this.flashMessagesService.show is not a function

Tags: angular5

Trying to use angular2-flash-messages and getting the console error _this.flashMessagesService.show is not a function

Followed steps per https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages

app.modules.ts

```
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

signin.component.ts has

```
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
```

signin.component.ts constructor has:

```
constructor(
private authService: AuthService,
private router: Router,
private flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService
) { }

onSubmit() {
this.authService.signin(this.email, this.password)
.then((res) => {
this.flashMessagesService.show('You are signed in', {
cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 4000
});
this.router.navigate(['/']);
})
.catch((err) => {
this.flashMessagesService.show(err.message, {
cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 4000
});
this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
});
}
```

and get the error _this.flashMessagesService.show is not a function

Answer (score 2):

```
   // put it inside of onSubmit() method
   var flashMessagesService = this.flashMessagesService;

  // and call it inside your .then function
  // Success
    flashMessagesService.show('You are signed in', {
       cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 4000
   });
  // Error
   flashMessagesService.show(err.message, {
      cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 4000
   });
```

Here you can check https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages/issues/35

Comment: If you are accessing `this.flashMessagesService.show` inside the `.then({})` block then it gives error. hold the `var fms = this.flashMeesagesService` and then use `fms.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Add the code

```
<flash-messages></flash-messages>
```

in app.component.html file.